# How to avoid to Time out Exception?

Tags: android, json, eclipse, connection, timeout

I'm trying to create an android application which depends on JSON responses. Sometimes it takes a lot of time for the server to respond and ends in a time out exception. Therefore I would like to add a restriction like my webservice call should abort after 20seconds if there is no response. Can you please help me achieving this idea.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Have you tried using nice networking libraries like [Volley](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html)?

Comment: HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParams, 20000);

Answer (score 0):

You're not giving much details on the actual implementation that you have.

However, messing with the timeout seems like it may be an emergency fix to an underlying problem that should be fixed.

However, using websockets for transport could be a possible (and probably more elegant) solution. They provide a persistent connection between client and server once created.

[Using websockets on Android and IOS](http://www.elabs.se/blog/66-using-websockets-in-native-ios-and-android-apps)

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to achieve the goal.

We can using **HttpURLConnection** to do the http request.

```
public String doPost() {
    if (!mIsNetworkAvailable) {
        return null;
    }

    try {
        URL url = new URL(mURL);
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        conn.setDoInput(true);
        for (String key : mHeadersMap.keySet()) {
            conn.setRequestProperty(key, mHeadersMap.get(key));
        }
        conn.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Android");
        conn.setConnectTimeout(30000);
        conn.setReadTimeout(30000);
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
        conn.getOutputStream().write(mContent);
        conn.getOutputStream().flush();
        int rspCode = conn.getResponseCode();
        if (rspCode >= 400) {
            return null;
        }

        byte[] buffer = new byte[8 * 1024];
        BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(conn.getInputStream());
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        int len;
        while ((len = bis.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            baos.write(buffer, 0, len);
        }
        baos.flush();
        final String result = new String(baos.toByteArray());
        baos.close();
        return result;
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

**setConnectTimeout** :Sets the maximum time in milliseconds to wait while connecting.

**setReadTimeout**:Sets the maximum time to wait for an input stream read to complete before giving up.

Reference: http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/URLConnection.html